# Difference between "question" and "query"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between a *question* and a *query*? It seems that in certain circumstances, the words are interchangeable:

> I have one further **question**.
>
> I have one further **query**.

But, other times they are not:

> The police officer **questioned** the man.
>
> The police officer **queried** the man.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [**Query**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/query?showCookiePolicy=true)
>   *noun*
>
> 1. a question, esp one expressing doubt, uncertainty, or an objection
> 2. *a less common name for* [*question mark*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/question-mark#question-mark_1)
>
> *verb*
>
> 3. to express uncertainty, doubt, or an objection concerning (something)
> 4. to express as a query ⇒ “What's up now?” she queried
> 5. (US) to put a question to (a person); *ask*

---

> **[Question](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/question)**
>   *noun*
>   <sub>(the first five uses are listed but there are a total of fifteen.)</sub>
>
> 1. a form of words addressed to a person in order to elicit information or evoke a response; interrogative sentence
> 2. a point at issue ⇒ "it's only a question of time until she dies",
> 3. a difficulty or uncertainty; doubtful point ⇒ "*a question of money*",  "*there's no question about it*"
> 4. (a) an act of asking
>        (b) an investigation into some problem or difficulty
> 5. a motion presented for debate by a deliberative body
>
> *verb*
>
> 16. to put a question or questions to (a person);                          interrogate
> 17. to make (something) the subject of dispute or disagreement
> 18. to express uncertainty about the validity, truth, etc, of (something); doubt
>
> Source: Collins Dictionary

### Differences between *question* and *query* as nouns

- You *ask* a question. NOT *You ask a query. ( * = incorrect)
- You *answer* a question. NOT *You answer a query.
- There are 10 multiple-choice questions on the exam. NOT *There are 10 multiple-choice queries on the exam.
- How to write a query letter. NOT *How to write a question letter.
- We regret that we cannot deal with queries on individual cases. (formal)
- An exam/test question. NOT *An exam/test query
- He popped the question (make a proposal of marriage). NOT *He popped the 
  query.
- Results of the [query](http://techterms.com/definition/query). Not *Results of the question
- (idiom) Something begs the question <sup>[1](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/question_1)</sup>. NOT *Something begs the query.
- The question *arises* as to whether… <sub><sup>([OXFORD LEARNERS DICTIONARY](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/question_1))</sup></sub>

**Common collocations with *question***: 
 - probing
 - direct
 - straight
 - difficult
 - personal
 - loaded 
 - rhetorical
 - controversial
 - awkward
 - embarrassing
 - inane
 - silly
 - tricky

**Common collocations with *query***: - specific - separate

**When the nouns *question* and *query* are synonymous**

- You *submit* queries or questions.
- You *raise* queries/questions
- If you *have* any questions/queries, please contact us.
- You *reply/respond* to a question/query.
- I would like *to put* a question to … (*formal*)
- I would like *to put* a query to … (*very formal*)
- Have you any questions/queries *about*…?

---

### Differences between *question* and *query* as verbs

Query is more formal and slightly outdated, and can be substituted with either *question* or the more common reporting verb, *ask*.

- She queried whether three months was long enough.
- "Any chance of a cup of tea?" he queried hopefully.
- She asked/questioned whether three months was long enough.
- "Any chance of a cup of tea?" he asked hopefully.

“He questioned hopefully” sounds a little odd to me, I doubt a native speaker would actually say this, although it might be acceptable in its written form.

**Similarities between *question* and *query* as verbs**

They are both transitive verbs and are sometimes interchangeable.

- The police officer questioned/queried him at some length.
- They questioned/queried her motives.

Comment: I guess you can also *answer* queries and questions and *reply/respond* to queries and questions. Furthermore you can *submit* queries and questions. You rather *pose* and *raise* questions but you'll find collocations with *query* in corpora as well.

Comment: Yes, you can respond and reply to questions. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Em1 it took me two years, but I finally got round to adding *submit* and *raise questions*, better late than never!

Answer (score 7):

Questions are more informal, broad, random, and can often be off-topic or out of context, spiraling into more discussion and debate.  You've heard the phrase "begging the question", but not "begging the query"... this sums up the notion that questions can open up a can of worms, whereas I've yet to experience a query being so chaotic.

A query can be the action (verb) of submitting a question (noun).  Queries are also used in computing as instructions you submit to a database to get results.  I agree with Preteesh in that queries are more technical and exact:  You send a query, you get a result.  My personal interpretation is that there is not much creative thought involved in delivering an answer to a query, but there can be in answering a question.

Comment: A good description can be found in [Use the right word by S.Hayakawa](http://www.amazon.com/Use-Right-Word-Modern-Synonyms/dp/B000ILDXU0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1374967171&sr=8-3) He says that "it is the seriousness of intent on the part of the person who poses a question that makes the question a query". Also, a *query* can be complex, thus implying creativity to be solved. But your first paragraph is very good.

Answer (score 6):

Oxford online says:

> ### Query
>
> #### noun (plural queries)
>
> a question, especially one expressing doubt or requesting information:
>   if you have any queries please telephone our office
>
> [...]
>
> #### verb (queries, querying, queried)
>
> [reporting verb]
>   ask a question about something, especially in order to express one's doubts about it or to check its validity or accuracy
>
> [...]

Comment: Do you have an example of a question which is not a query?

Comment: @Theta30, the question is whether one really has to look very far to find a question that’s not a query. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

*Query* implies an official/technical doubt or question,
whereas *Question* implies general question or doubt.

*Query* is a subset of *Question*.

Comment: This use of the word "doubt" as a synonym of question is mainly limited to Indian English. In other English speaking regions it would be regarded as an error.

Answer (score 2):

In general usage, I would say that when you have a query about something, you're not quite sure whether your question is a question or not, or what the actual question is, as distinct from those occasions when you know what the question is, but you don't know what the answer to it is. Someone may say something for instance, that you may feel the need to query, because you sense there's something about it that's not quite right, but you don't know precisely what it is.

Answer (score 2):

When you *question* something you are not always putting forth a *query*, but sometimes you are of polemical disposition.

> Questioning the authoritarian laws of the state.

Whereas *query* invariably means an inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

A [query](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/query) is "a question that you ask because you want information or because you are not certain about something [Macmillan]."

Oxford defines a [query](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/query?q=query) **more specifically** than a [question](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/question?q=question); a *question* is

> a sentence worded or expressed so as to elicit information

while a *query* is

> a question, especially one **expressing doubt** or **requesting information** [emphasis mine]

Comment: Gotta love these "experts" who downvote a quote from a reputable dictionary.

Comment: I guess the downvote tells you that you haven't answered the question. Or was it a query? OP wanted to get information. OP was uncertain about that. It must be a query, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this and many others, I recommend you compare the etymology of the words, even if this "only" will give you the history of the words and not necessarily the current, modern meaning. There are so many words in English which have their roots in French, Latin etc. In the case of query vs question, they both seem to originate from the same meaning (in Latin):

"question" is derived from Anglo-French *questiun*, Old French question *question*, "difficulty, problem; legal inquest, interrogation, torture" from Latin *quaestionem* (nominative *quaestio*) "a seeking, a questioning, inquiry, examining, judicial investigation" noun of action from past participle stem of *quaerere* "ask, seek".

"query" originates in Latin *quaere* "ask," imperative of *quaerere*. (see above)

My interpretation/guess: perhaps "question" is closer to the noun-form, while "query" is closer to the verb, even if both can be used as nouns/verbs.

Comment: I like etymology but don't see how it explains the difference here

Answer (score 0):

They have distinct meanings in computer science as well.

Whenever a computer sends a request for a small amount of information to another computer, it is a *query*, or a *request* when the amount of information is not small. For example, the `ping` command asks for a response of negligible length to confirm the existence of another computer; `ping` is a query. However, a computer asks for an entire file to be sent, it is described as a *request*.

*Question* is used only when a computer requires human input. Synonyms here are *input* and  *prompt*.

Answer (score 0):

I consider "query", noun and verb, a simple variant of "question", especially as both words are derived from the same Latin verb queri, perfect quaestus sum. The normal word is question, the variant query is relatively rare.

Google Ngram question, query [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=question%2C%20query&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquestion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquery%3B%2Cc0)