# Word which describes a thing which is to be considered

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm after a word to use as a heading for a list of questions which need consideration.

This list of questions is adhoc and will not be repeated - they are specific to a single document which, once it's served it's purpose, will never be reused.

"Considerations" means something different, I keep coming back to phrases and am now suffering mental block.

"Ponderings" seems to imply it is something that I've thought about but these items are things I want other people to think about.

Phrases which describe the word I'm after would be things such as:

- Things to be considered
- Questions to be considered
- Things to be thought about

My particular list is to do with a human resources issue and, having addressed various issues elsewhere in my document, I'm left with a residual list of questions which need to be considered such as:

- should ZHCEs accrue annual leave whilst taking annual leave?
- should ZHCEs be allowed to transfer annual leave across leave periods?
- under what circumstances should ZHCEs be allowed to take leave before it has been accrued?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean some kind of [checklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checklist)?

Comment: @iterums Good call but it's not what I'm after - there's a fault with my question (which I will now fix).  A checklist implies (I think) a set set of things to be considered and actioned, I'm after a non-set set of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Agenda** means a list of things that need to be acted upon.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after a word like "Agenda" but with the meaning being "thought about" rather than "acted upon".

Comment: You could coin *Cogitata* (cf *agenda*) but *agenda* **can** simply mean *things to be done.* Because it's a familiar name for lists of meeting items, where they are considered, it is probably the best "standard" easily-understood word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Understood but I'm really after the core meaning of the word to be that it needs to be thought about - I don't particularly care about the word containing the concept of a list.  I'm fine to use a plural instead.  +1 for "Cogitata".

Comment: _Cogitata_ would describe things which **had** been thought about. To match _agenda_ it would have to be _cogitanda_, but I don’t think most people would understand either.

Comment: @BarrieEngland People probably wouldn't understand it but it's an awesome name for a website/company :)

Comment: It seems there isn't a single word which accurately encapsulates what I'm after; Agenda/Cogitanda is as good as it gets - I've chickened out an used a phrase as my heading.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider

> - subjects
> - issues
> - items
> - topics
> - points
> - interests
> - matters
> - themes
> - concerns

SUPPLEMENT

Perhaps *[conundrum](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conundrums)*

> a puzzling question or problem

Comment: +1, I would also add _questions_.

Comment: Thank you, but these are all a little broad; I was wondering if there was a specific word which means "A list of things to be thought about".

Comment: @terdon If there was a word which was the plural of "questions to be thought about", I'd be happy!  "Questions" by itself seems to lack intent.

Comment: @GHC could you add a couple of these issues to your question so we can better understand what you are after?

Comment: @terdon I will.  I'm going to post "Queries" as an answer to see what people think.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the quite simple

> "Up for consideration."

No action is required, only consideration, whether through discussion, debate, the weighing of pros and cons, or a stringent and thorough-going dialectic (though *consideration* may obviate this mode of interaction).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm after a single word if possible

Comment: @GHC:  OK, how about "ponderables"?

Comment: I considered "Ponderings" in my question and dismissed it as (I feel) it implies something I've thought about myself rather than something that someone else should think about

Comment: How about "brainstorming"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm drawn to "Queries" (thanks to @terdon for "Questions" which got me thinking about this).  As I understand it a query is a more defined form of question.  See [Difference between "question" and "query"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/difference-between-question-and-query)

What do people think?

Comment: The problem with *queries* or *questions* is that they suggest the matter to be considered is phrased as an interrogatory. In many case (and you would know best about yours), the discussion can be driven by questions, statements, fragments or even single words.

Comment: @bib That's a fair point - in my specific example, the items are phased as interrogatory; I'd still be interested to see if there was a word which covered the general concept.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are all things that need 'to be' done you could put them in the category of

***pending***

or if you prefer

***residuals***