# Idiom for the Appearance of a Quæstion

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom like ‘the quæstion raises itself, whether …’?

Comment: *The question **arises***, whether . . .*

Comment: Did you deliberately spell “question” with *æ* , or is that a typo?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It appears to be deliberate and an allusion to the word's etymology. That would be a tough typo to make!

Comment: Easier for someone in Norway: https://www.google.com/search?q=NOrwegian+keyboard&num=20&newwindow=1&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=tRZcU9YMdVJLGM%253A%253BMXRUdr8_sBtrJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fascii-table.com%25252Fkeyboard.php%25252F281N&source=iu&pf=m&fir=tRZcU9YMdVJLGM%253A%252CMXRUdr8_sBtrJM%252C_&biw=1378&bih=960&usg=__7xBxiOSb_o5YNDBElKneWyTgmNM%3D&ved=0CC8QyjdqFQoTCPmKu6vB28cCFYl6Pgod14wPTw&ei=jJPoVfmUL4n1-QHXmb74BA#imgrc=tRZcU9YMdVJLGM%3A&usg=__7xBxiOSb_o5YNDBElKneWyTgmNM%3D

Comment: related: [Difference between “question” and “query”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/difference-between-question-and-query/120008#120008)

Comment: There's also the colloquialism ['which begs the question'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beg_a_question); most commonly used these days if the question is actually rhetorical, or the likely answer is already apparent.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for **arise**, also a question may **reveal itself**, **show itself** and **rear its head**. In either 3 cases you would not preface the question with whether:

> The question reveals itself: Why would they turn the device on, if not to use it?
>
> ...and thus the real question rears its foul head: Why would they betray all that they know, only to have it...?

PS: You don't need to insult the head.. It's just fun to do :)

PPS: A question may arise out of the blue, however for a question to reveal itself (or any of the other two) generally you need to prod at it first, eg. through a discussion that leads to the question.